# VK API: Выбрать только Российские города по City ID

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Я работаю с методом users.search VK API, чтобы получить список пользователей по определенному запросу:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.search?q=' + searchQuery + '&count=1000&fields=city&online=0&has_photo=0&country=1&access_token=' + accessToken + '&v=5.57
```

Как вы видите, я указал country=1, что значит, что мне нужны пользователи только из России. Далее я хочу получить список городов, в которых проживают первые 1000 пользователей (если они указали город), однако в полученном объекте присутствуют города также из других стран. Как я могу их отсеять (желательно, без дополнительного запроса к API)? Можно ли это сделать просто по ID (например, если город с ID > 150 000, значит он не в России)?

Comment: Можете предоставить пример запроса к API и пример ответа? Я сейчас проверил - мне в объекте `city` с указанием `country` = 1 возвращаются только российские города. Также заполнить поле `city` пользователь может только со страницы редактирования своих контактов, где идет жесткая привязка городов к странам.

Comment: @terron, вы правы! Вывод городов я делал на карту через геокодинг с транслитерацией, видимо некоторые города он по ошибке находил в других странах. Добавил к запросу +Russia и все встало на свои места.